# Windows Docker Enterprise 2019 Host: How to communicate with host applications from Linux container?

Tags: linux, docker, windows-server-2019

As the title says: Windows Docker Enterprise 2019 Host: How to communicate with host applications from Linux container?

I'm running a Windows Server 2019 server with Docker Enterprise installed on it. I would like to run Linux containers with it. I have native Windows service applications running on the Windows Server which I would like my Linux container to communicate with. How does the Linux container communicate with the Windows service?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run linux containers on a Windows worker (even if its doable, I would definitly not do that).

The only way would be to create a swarm with Linux and Windows workers, and deploy a stack on said swarm.

In the yml file for the stack, you must use the "placement" option so the containers runs on the correct OS.